# Macbook Pro 2019 Catalina won't read SD card

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I've used this exact same USB hub and SD card in the past, and it's worked fine, but all of a sudden the SD card won't appear on my computer anymore.

It's not the USB hub or the SD card reader, because it works perfectly fine with two other Macs, it's not the SD card either as that shows up on other Macs via this USB hub/SD card reader, but it's also not the port on my Macbook, because my external hard drive shows up via this USB hub, just not the SD card.

I've resetted SMC and done PRAM/NVRAM (<kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> on start up) resets also, checked Finder preferences, etc..

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Do _other_ SD cards show up on the MBP '19 on the same reader, or just this one particular SD card?

Comment: Also - if you reformat the SD card on a Mac which _can_ read it, can the card then be read on the MBP '19?